# Angular UI Bootstrap - I can open and close a modal just once

Tags: user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a weird problem with a modal. It should be a absolutely normal modal that I can open and close many times, but I can open just one and also just close one time! http://plnkr.co/ksTy0HdifAJDhDf4jcNr

My **index.html** file looks this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-include src="'widget.html'" ng-controller="WidgetCtrl"></div>
  <!-- other widgets and content -->
</body>
```

As you can see I have devided my application in different parts (called widgets), that I am including per ng-include in my index html file. Every widget has it's own controller.

The **widget.html** looks like this:

```
<div modal="theModal">
    <div class="modal-header"><h3>The Modal</h3></div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Body intentionally left blank
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="CloseModal()">ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- more modals and other stuff -->
<button ng-click="OpenModal()">open modal</button>
```

And now the widget controller (which is a child controller of the main controller)

```
app.controller('WidgetCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.OpenModal  = function() { $scope.theModal = true; }
  $scope.CloseModal = function() { $scope.theModal = false;}
});
```

All stuff for opening and closing the modal is part of the sub controller (WidgetCtrl) and therefore shouldn't conflict with anything from the parent controller.

`$scope.theModal` is in the beginning `undefined`, so the modal is not shown. With a click on the button `$scope.theModal` is defined and set to `true`; this is triggered by Angular UI and the modal is shown. On a click of ok, the now existing `$scope.theModal` is set to `false` and the modal disappears. Everything is perfect but .. it's not working again!

Comment: Your link won't load for me, but shouldn't the first line of widget be `<div ng-show="theModal">`?

Comment: @Jim: Hi Jim, Plnkr is a bit slow today. I think they have performance issues. :(
I'm using [Angular-UI-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). Therefore the attribute `modal` is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to include `close="CloseModal()"` in the first div of your widget

```
<div modal="theModal" close="CloseModal()">
  <div class="modal-header"><h3>The Modal</h3></div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Body intentionally left blank
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="CloseModal()">ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/24hHgMdcrQFudr0Ap0Ac?p=preview)

Comment: Great, thank you! But can you explain, why this must be? `CloseModal()` is now called twice; so `$scope.theModal` is set twice to `false`. For me it's not really logic but I'm happy for the solution!

Comment: This is a problem that will be fixed eventually, I just submitted a report on github, check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LNeDugtLMUMt5uMOqDfT?p=preview), lines 48-50, if we remove that promise from dialog.open() the directive will work fine without the close attribute.

Comment: This is a nice and simple solution, but it doesn't seem to work with newer versions of angularjs and ui-bootstrap, for example  angularjs 1.0.8 and ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js.